# Vue 3 class-based-component doesn't call hook method

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3

I'm trying to get a little bit famliar with vue 3.

I wrote a class based component and try to call the mounded() Lifecycle method.

But for some reasons it doesn't work. The documentation isn't helpfull at this point to me.

So any help would be nice.

Here is the class:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <Header />
    <div class="container mrgnbtm">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <!--<CreateUser @createUser="userCreate($event)" />-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <!--<DisplayBoard :numberOfUsers="numberOfUsers" @getAllUsers="getAllUsers()" />-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mrgnbtm">
      <Users v-if="users.length > 0" :users="users" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
import { userService } from "../services/UserService";
import Header from "./Header.vue";
import CreateUser from "./CreateUser.vue";
import DisplayBoard from "./DisplayBoard.vue";
import Users from "./Users.vue";

Vue.registerHooks(
  ['beforeRouteEnter',
  'mounted']
)

@Options({
  components: {
    Header,
    CreateUser,
    DisplayBoard,
    Users,
  },
})

export default class Dashboard extends Vue {
  
  users: any;
  numberOfUsers = 0;

  getAllUsers() {
    userService.getAllUsers().then((response) => {
      console.log("Call UserService");
      this.users = response.json;
      this.numberOfUsers = this.users;
    });
  }

  userCreate(data: any) {
    console.log("data:::", data);
    userService.createUser(data).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      this.getAllUsers();
    });
  }

  mounted() {
    console.log("mounted");
    this.getAllUsers();
  }

}
</script>
```

In case that mounted() isn't called, users is allways null.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem (`mounted` hook is always run in my classes). Note you don't need to call `registerHooks` for `mounted`. Also, `users` is not initialized, and your template will try to access `users.length` before the async `getAllUsers()` resolves, which will lead to an error. Can you link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Toni19.

The error was, that users wasn't initialized.

So I changed this an now all is working as expected.

Thanks